# PAD Shining Goddess of Secrets, Kali team?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

I'm rank 75, and want to build a Light Kali team without spending too much money. Right now I have a evoed, lvl 54, 3 awakened LKali, a max level unevoed Sun Quan (working on the evo mats right now), max level unevoed Gryps Rider, and two other monsters on my team (not enough cost to support, and no good subs). I know that Sun Quan is a good sub (his active for spiking past tough bosses), and I use my Gryps Rider as a dual orb changer. I was wondering which subs I should work for(and whether or not they are REM build), and what type of team I should use (good actives or god/healer type). Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/PuzzleAndDragons/wiki/lkali

Comment: @NiteCyper I think you meant [reddit.com/r/PuzzleAndDragons/wiki/guides/leaders/lkali](https://www.reddit.com/r/PuzzleAndDragons/wiki/guides/leaders/lkali)

Comment: @ObliviousSage Or back then that was where it used to be: http://web.archive.org/web/20150105060127/http://www.reddit.com/r/PuzzleAndDragons/wiki/lkali

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm rank 171 and have a decent LKali team. I have a max level, fully awakened evoed Kali with a few dozen +s.

I also have a Sun Quan: max level, fully awakened, ult evoed (light) with 1 +. You're correct, he is a great sub for LKali.
 
I managed to pull another LKali pretty recently, and am working on leveling her.

Do you have Fuma Kotaro?
 
His skill (wood to light) is incredibly useful. Sadly for me, he's only level 30 or so right now, but fully awakened and ult evoed. TPAs are quite useful. I use Echidna for delay or Fire Valk for her skill (heal to fire). I use an eight-star Light Valk sometimes for her stats.
 
I like God/Healers, as they are easy to work with even in other teams. Riders are very useful, but I haven't pulled any. :(

I encourage you to play with a LKali team. The subs are interchangeable, which is why I love having her. Obviously the best subs are LKali herself as well as DKali (if you can pull either).

Good luck and hope this kind of helps! :D